# 1 Eclipse project, 2 artifacts with Gradle

Tags: eclipse, gradle, moreunit

I want to create structure for my new project and I intend to build it with Gradle. I already know that if I place sources and tests in one project plugins like MoreUnit will handle it easily and create tests for my classes right where I want them.

However it creates some awkward dependency issues when my project consists of several subprojects depending on each other - to be precise when I want to use some common code in tests in project A and then reuse it in tests in project B I had to do some workarounds like

```
project(':B') {
  // ...
  dependencies {
    // ...
    if (noEclipseTask) {
      testCompile project(':A').sourceSets.test.output
    }
  }
}
```

sometimes there were also some evaluation problem so another hack had to be introduced:

```
project(':B') {
  evaluationDependsOn(':A')
}
```

Splitting this into 2 separate projects got rid of that issue but then MoreUnit no longer was able to trace where it should create new test files, and mark which methods have been tested. I haven't found anything in MoreUnit config that would allow me to fix that, so am trying to fix this from Gradle side.

Can we arrange things so I can have several subprojects, sources and tests are arranged in maven like manner (`project/src/java`, `project/test/java`) but tests and sources will create separate artifacts? If I am solving the wrong problem then how should I solve the right one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create some `testenv` jar for common like:

```
sourceSets {
    testenv {
        compileClasspath += main.output
        runtimeClasspath += main.output
    }
}

configurations {
    testenvCompile {
        extendsFrom runtime
    }
    testCompile {
        extendsFrom testenvRuntime
    }
    testenvDefault {
        extendsFrom testenvRuntime
    }
}
```

and

```
task testenvJar(type: Jar, group: 'build', description: 'Assembles a jar archive containing the testenv classes.') {
    from sourceSets.testenv.output

    appendix = 'testenv'

    // add artifacts to testenvRuntime as task 'jar' does automatically (see JavaPlugin#configureArchivesAndComponent:106 and http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html, "Figure 23.2. Java plugin - dependency configurations")
    configurations.testenvRuntime.artifacts.add new org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.publish.ArchivePublishArtifact(testenvJar)
}

task testenvSourcesJar(type: Jar, group: 'build', description: 'Assembles a jar archive containing all testenv sources.') {
    from sourceSets.testenv.allSource

    appendix = 'testenv'
    classifier = 'sources'
}

artifacts {
    archives testenvJar
    archives testenvSourcesJar
}
```

and use it in your depended projects like

```
    testCompile project(path: ':common', configuration: 'testenvDefault')
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for reply! I have some doubts that I'd like to resolve. By common do you mean test code that I want to share among test projects? Should your solution be applied to 1-project-with-src-and-test or 2-separate-projects approach? Should first piece of code be placed on root project level or within commons project?

Comment: All the code above can be applied to a common project which is generating ```common-v1.0.jar``` and ```common-testenv-v1.0.jar```. Both can be used for their purposes ...